# while selecting rows on jtable using keyboard up and down keys focus is lost

Tags: java, swing

```
aPanel.getTable().setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
aPanel.getTable().requestFocusInWindow();
```

Still the focus gets lost and we had to regain it using mouse click.

jtable focus is lost on scrolling using up and down arrow keys and focus gets shifted to other component say button. How to regain focus to continue scrolling on rows the problem occurs for java 8.

Comment: Sounds like `fireDataTableChanged()` is robbing your focus and giving it to something else. Do you override that method in your tablemodel?

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what you are doing based on two line of code. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: yes i have called fireDataTableChanged() on tablemodel -@blahfunk

Comment: What components does `fireDataTableChanged()` touch?

Comment: @Riya, well you should NOT be invoking that method. The is the job of the `TableModel`. Without knowing the context of why you think you need to invoke that method we can't help. Post your `SSCCE`. We don't have time to play 20 questions.

Comment: i cannot provide a full sscce since it is previously written code and distributed in several classes but thanks for looking into the issue    @camickr

Comment: fireDataTableChanged is invoked on table model which is supplied to in a panel constructor to create panels because for that panel data changes . but y is that affecting the table focus the table which is in another panel .@blahfunk

Comment: @Riya, The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the problem. So first you get the logic working in a SSCCE and then you figure out how the real code is different. If you code is spread out over multiple classes how do you expect us to guess what you are doing based on two lines of code???

Comment: `fireDataTableChanged is invoked on table model` - and you have already been told you should NOT be doing this. You have improper design of your code. If you can't post a SSCCE we can't suggest on how to redesign.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableName.requestFocus();
```

Solution: Your table doesn't know when to lose or gain focus, we have to mention explicitly this into our Table in ListSelectionListener event. requestFocus() will ensure this functionality.

will work in this case as it will prevent losing focus from the table. Please Note: no changes required in fireDataTableChanged(); method